# Problem when trying to print messages received from more clients

Tags: php

Let me explain the problem: I'm creating a system that use sensors able to read some data, then, each sensor, will have to send those data to a server that will print each message received in a new line on the page.

Sensor.php

```
class Sensor extends Thread implements ISensor
{
    ....

    public function readValue(){
        $this->value = rand( -15 , 40 );
        $this->timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    public function run(){
        $number = 0;
        $this->socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Couldn't create socket");
        $this->connectionResult = socket_connect($this->socket, $this->ip, (int)$this->port) or die("Couldn't connect to server");
        while($number <= $this->requestNumber){
            $number = $number + 1;
            $this->readValue();
            $this->sendData();
            sleep($this->frequency);
        }
        socket_close($this->socket);
    }

    public function sendData(){
        $input = $this->toString();
        socket_write($this->socket, $input, strlen($input)) or die ("Impossible send message");
    }
```

Server.php

```
set_time_limit (300);
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 19000;

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');
socket_listen($sock);

while (true) {
    $client = socket_accept($sock);
    while (0 != socket_recv($client, $message, 1024, 0))
    {
        echo $message . "<br>";
    }
    socket_close($client);
}
socket_close($sock);
```

The expected result was that the clients are able to connect to the server and send messages (this works fine) while the server just print a new line for each message received.

That partially works, I will explain better with a screenshot (I'm actually unable to post screenshot, I will leave a link to the screenshot image if you can't understand the problem with the text description under)

[image]

The first sensor keep sending all the messages and the server print them corretly then, when the thread ends, the server just output a whole line of all the messagges received from the second second sensor while the first was still running and then print the messages like it should.

It's because of the while loop? If I remove the while loop the server just print one single message for each sensors.

Comment: You generally don't need to apologize for your English. Most people here don't really care as long as you're understandable, and will gladly fix any grammar issues you may have in the post.

Comment: @zoe I saw the edits, thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to understand what are you trying to accomplish. Why sockets? Why not a simple HTTP POST?.

Comment: Usually I don't play with threads but maybe try `ob_flush(); flush();` after `echo $message . "<br>";`, just a guess

Comment: Thanks Viney for the suggestion, i will try it as soon as i can! Sal, it's a project requisite, i can't do in other ways.

Comment: @Viney tried the solution but php report this notice: ob_flush(): failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found the solution.

After hours and hours of web searching i finally found the correct keywoard that showed me a page with this code

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Set time limit to indefinite execution
set_time_limit(0);

// Set the ip and port we will listen on
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 15000;

//Implicit Flush
ob_implicit_flush();

// Create a TCP Stream socket
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

// Bind the socket to an address/port
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');

// Start listening for connections
socket_listen($sock);

// Non block socket type
socket_set_nonblock($sock);

// Clients
$clients = [];
// Loop continuously
while (true) {
    // Accept new connections
    if ($newsock = socket_accept($sock)) {
        if (is_resource($newsock)) {
            // Set Non-block for the new connection
            socket_set_nonblock($newsock);
            // Append the new connection to the clients array
            $clients[] = $newsock;
        }
    }
    // Polling for new messages
    if (count($clients)) {
        foreach ($clients AS $k => $v) {
            // Check for new messages
            $string = '';
            if ($char = socket_read($v, 1024)) {
                $string .= $char;
            }
            // New string for a connection
            if ($string) {
                echo "$string <br>";
            } else {
                if ($seconds > 30) {
                    // Ping every 5 seconds for live connections
                    if (false === socket_write($v, 'PING')) {
                        // Close non-responsive connection
                        socket_close($clients[$k]);
                        // Remove from active connections array
                        unset($clients[$k]);
                    }
                    // Reset counter
                    $seconds = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sleep(1);
    $seconds++;
}
// Close the master sockets
socket_close($sock);
```

And works perfectly!

Thanks guys for the help, i post the auto-anwser in case someone else is having a similar issue.